# Iteratively define user-defined discrete distributions

Tags: r, apply

I am writing a script that, using `-distr-`, defines some discrete distributions based on the following objects:

```
margins <- c("discrete1", "discrete2")

vec1 <- list(support=c(0,1,2), probabilities=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.6))
vec2 <- list(support=c(12,14,20), probabilities=c(0.1, 0.15, 0.75))
```

Here you have the code that works as expeced: it creates the two distributions.

```
library("distr")

discrete1 <- DiscreteDistribution (supp = vec1[[1]], prob = vec1[[2]])
ddiscrete1 <- d(discrete1)  # Density function
pdiscrete1 <- p(discrete1)  # Distribution function
qdiscrete1 <- q(discrete1)  # Quantile function
rdiscrete1 <- r(discrete1)  

discrete2 <- DiscreteDistribution (supp = vec2[[1]], prob = vec2[[2]])
ddiscrete2 <- d(discrete2) 
pdiscrete2 <- p(discrete2) 
qdiscrete2 <- q(discrete2) 
rdiscrete2 <- r(discrete2)
```

Once the two (or possibly more) distributions are defined, my final goal is to sample random numbers from them:

```
rdiscrete1(100)
rdiscrete2(100)
```

The problem with this code is that the number of distributions can be very high.. I wonder how it could be possible to automatize the creation of the functions in a more elegant manner.

Also, I need the two functions to be of class `DiscreteDistribution` and not as nested in lists (see `is(discrete1)` in my example).

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you want the final result to be. It seems like you are creating way too many variables to keep track of with unique names. It really seems like you should be working with lists here to store all the distributions so you can easily access them.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's now clear. Thanks, S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l <- list(list(support = c(0, 1, 2), probabilities = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.6)),
          list(support = c(12, 14, 20), probabilities = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.75)))

distrs <- lapply(1:length(l), function(n) {
  d <- DiscreteDistribution(supp = l[[n]][[1]], prob = l[[n]][[2]])
  list(d = d, dd = d(d), pd = p(d), qd = q(d), rd = r(d))
})

# First object of class DiscreteDistribution 
is(distrs[[1]][[1]])
# [1] "DiscreteDistribution"        "UnivariateDistribution"      "AcDcLcDistribution"         
# [4] "Distribution"                "UnivDistrListOrDistribution"

# Random numbers
dim(sapply(distrs, function(x) x[[5]](100)))
# [1] 100   2
```

Comment: @Stezzo, is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think you are very close. I agree about the partial unclarity, I am editing the question

Comment: @Stezzo, what about this? Although `DiscreteDistribution` objects are in the list they are perfectly fine.

Comment: I tried your suggested code. If I type `distrs[[1]]$rd(100)` It samples from the 1st distribution, but the dd, pd, qd, rd are nested in lists and I need to have the overall function of class DiscreteDistribution. I tried to use unlist but I am not able to figure out the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, this answer to the present question. If I have problems in using such functions as marginal distributions with the `-copula-` package I will post an ad hoc question. Thank yu very much for your time!